# Multiple paths in NSIS. Code doesnt get executed

Tags: nsis

I need to ask user for several paths before installation, but i cannot get it done in NSIS. Seems like my code doesnt get referenced in MUI:

```
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
!define MUI_ICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\modern-install.ico""
!define MUI_UNICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\modern-uninstall.ico"
!define MUI_CUSTOMPAGECOMMANDS
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_COMPONENTS_LEAVE ComponentPost
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_DIRECTORY_SHOW DirectoryShow
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_DIRECTORY_LEAVE DirectoryLeave
```

And at compilation I get

```
  install function "ComponentPost" not referenced - zeroing code (0-2) out

  install function "DirectoryShow" not referenced - zeroing code (2-49) out

  install function "DirectoryLeave" not referenced - zeroing code (49-61) out
```

Obviously, it the code of these three functions doesnt get executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First time I see **!define MUI_CUSTOMPAGECOMMANDS** and some others. There is no reference for them in NSIS or manual. What are them?

If you want to add page Directory into your installer use macro named **MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY** (and not MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE)

To add PRE/SHOW/LEAVE functions for this page use

```
MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE function
MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW function
MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE function
```

These defines should be set before inserting a page macro.

I think the easiest way for you is to modify an existing example (can be found in NSIS\Examples directory), your script does not make a sense at all.

Comment: iirc, MUI_ DIRECTORYPAGE is the syntax of MUI 1.x, you can still find many instances of it on the nsis wiki